# Goblin PC Natural Attack

Tags: pathfinder-1e, unarmed-combat, natural-weapon, goblin

If a Goblin PC has the "Hard Head, Big Teeth" racial trait, do they modify their bite attack modifier to deal x1.5 damage or leave it at x1.

Example: STR Mod=2 
Bite +5. Deals 1d4 + 2

Or

Bite +5 Deals 1d4 +3

Answer (score 4):

Per [the rules on natural attacks](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#Table_Natural_Attacks_by_Size), creatures add 1.5x strength modifier to their natural attack if they have only one natural attack. The relevant quote from the above link is:

> If a creature has only one natural attack, it is always made using the creature’s full base attack bonus and adds 1-1/2 times the creature’s Strength bonus on damage rolls. This increase does not apply if the creature has multiple attacks but only takes one.

The Hard Head, Big Teeth trait for goblins doesn't change this. If your bite attack is your only natural attack, and you don't try to combine it with your normal weapon attacks, it'll get 1.5x strength modifier to its damage.

Comment: You can improve this answer pointing out that they gain a **primary** natural attack. *Goblins with this trait gain a bite attack as a primary natural attack*.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it counted a PCs ability to make unarmed strikes into this, since unarmed strikes are considered natural attacks.

Comment: @John-D-Frogman Unarmed Strikes don't count as natural attacks. See www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/strike-unarmed/

Comment: @John-D-Frogman So far as I'm aware, unarmed strikes fall into a weird gray area. That is, they aren't really natural attacks as *every* creature, I think, *can* make unarmed strikes—a bear can totally haul off and sock a dude, for example—, it's just many creatures A) aren't proficient with unarmed strikes, B) provoke attacks of opportunity when they use an unarmed strike, and C) deal more damage with other attacks, so they gravitate instead toward their *actual* natural attacks (like a bite) or, y'know, manufactured weapons.